# fourier series of absolute value of function

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to find the Fourier series of

$$ |\cos(x)| \text{ from } -\pi \leq x<\pi$$

I know that the $$ b_n $$ terms go to 0 because we have the integrand as an odd function of x.

But how can I solve for

$$a_n? $$

I know that $$a_n $$ is even and that

$$ a_n = 1/\pi\int |\cos(x)|\cos(n\pi) $$

But I am not sure how to solve this.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the variable $l$ here? Usually, $l$ is a bad letter to use as a variable, because it is hard to distinguish from the numeral $1$. If you must, use the script $\ell$, LaTeX `\ell`. In any event, I think there is no value of $l$ for which that is the correct formula...

Comment: Wait—isn't it an _even_ function?

Comment: if $f$ is even, or odd, then $|f|$ is even. $\cos$ is even, so your function is even.

Comment: I know that my function is even...The b_n term was odd as it has sine with it

Comment: I just need to know how to integrate this, any ideas?

Comment: Made some edits, that make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f$ is even, you can find your coefficients as
\begin{align}
a_0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\cos(x)|dx\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)dx - \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos(x)dx\\
a_n &= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}|\cos(x)|\cos(nx)dx\\
&= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\cos(nx)dx - \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\cos(x)\cos(nx)dx
\end{align}
Useful identity to use
$$
\cos[(n+1)x]+\cos[(n-1)x] = 2\cos(x)\cos(nx)
$$

Comment: Can you explain how you go from step 3 to step 4?

Comment: @JacksonHart $x^2$ is even so $$\int_{-1}^1x^2dx = 2\int_0^1x^2dx$$ correct?

Comment: Are you sure we can say this though? I feel like this argument only is correct because a Fourier series is periodic, but would not be correct otherwise

Comment: @JacksonHart all even integrals can be written as 2 times the integral over half the original domain.

Comment: OK. And we solve this with integration by parts?

Comment: Are you sure, neither would reduce out?

Comment: but should it really effect the domain of the other intergral it is multiplied by? I mean I see what you are saying, it just seems weird that you can substitute like this and change domain of both integrals

Comment: @JacksonHart I dont understand your comment.

Comment: where did you find that identity?

Comment: Manipulation of $\cos(a+b)$ rules http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: so now 4 integrals?

Comment: Case $n=1$ is zero so only consider $n\neq 1$ and all easy integrals to handle.

Comment: @JacksonHart it can be done by int by parts as well.